# Arduino simple button activated light

Tags: arduino

I keep getting an error when I run this code any solutions?

```
{
pinMode(button2pin, INPUT, 3);
  button1State= digitalRead(button1Pin 2);
}
  if (button1State == LOW)
{

}
```

Comment: `digitalRead(button1Pin 2)` The syntax is incorrect. Include the actual error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This code presumes that you have connected one side of your switch to digital pin 3 and the other side to ground and that your button is normally open.

```
const int button2pin = 3;
int button2State = 0;

void setup(){

    pinMode(button2pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin(9600); // for debug only

}

void loop(){

    button2State = digitalRead(button2pin);

    if(button2State == LOW){

        Serial.print("Button 2 pressed"); // for debug only

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This project turns on the light when the button is pressed. Maybe can help you with your problem.

```
int buttonPin = 2;
int ledPin = 5;

//This var read the state of Buttonpin

int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {

// set the pin as output
pinMode(ledPin , OUTPUT);

// set the pin as input
pinMode(buttonPin , INPUT);
}

void loop(){
// read the button state

buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin );

if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
}
```